# Entity Framework: Common entity for one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement one-many relationship with common entity solution in entity framework code first using inheritance. Its not creating desired results. I need this schema:

```
CommonEntity    Address         Licensee    User
--------------  -------------   ----------- ---------
CID(PK)         AddressID(PK)   CID(FK/PK)  CID(FK/PK)
AddressID(FK)
```

CommonEntity:

```
public class CommonEntity{
     [key]
     public int CID{get;set;}
     public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Address:

```
public class Address{
     [key]
     public int AddressID{get;set;}
     public string country{get;set;}
}
```

Licensee:

```
public class Licensee{
     [key]
     [ForeignKey("CommonEntity")]
     public int CID{get;set;}
     public string CompanyName{get;set;}
}
```

User:

```
public class User{
     [key]
     [ForeignKey("CommonEntity")]
     public int CID{get;set;}
     public string UserName{get;set;}
     public string Pass{get;set;}
}
```

DbContext Class:

```
public class DataModelContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CommonEntity> CommonEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Above code is giving this exception:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'CommonID' on type
>   'TestingEF.Models.Licensee' is not valid. The navigation property
>   'CommonEntity' was not found on the dependent type
>   'TestingEF.Models.Licensee'. The Name value should be a valid
>   navigation property name.

Comment: When you use `[ForeignKey("CommonEntity")]`, you also need a navigation property `public virtual CommonEntity CommonEntity { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution my by self.
Models:

```
public class CommonEntity{
     [key]
     public int CID{get;set;}

     public long AddressId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Address")]
     public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class Address{
     [key]
     public int AddressID{get;set;}
     public string country{get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<CommonEntity> CommonEntity { get; set; }
}
[Table("Licensee")]
public class Licensee{
     public string CompanyName{get;set;}
}
[Table("User")]
public class User{
     public string UserName{get;set;}
     public string Pass{get;set;}
}
```

Dbcontext Class:

```
public class DataModelContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<CommonEntity> CommonEntity { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is quite different from the model your posted in your question. In above model Licensee/User class will not be part of model. it is creating 2 one-to-many relationships (in different directions between `CommonEntity` & `Address`

Comment: Yes its different model. Issue was in my model layout and i find out that and fixed it.